# When the partition key is the primary key, is it possible that 2 different items are saved into the same partition?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When the partition key is the primary key, is it possible that 2 different items are saved into the same partition?

I checked the documents, and it says dynamodb will calculate the hash value of the partition key to decide which partition an item will be save to.
Is it possible that 2 different items have the same hash value?

Comment: DynamoDB doesn't expose the internal hashing algorithm, but the hash must be unique for each item. Otherwise, it will be a bad choice of the hashing algorithm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items with different partition key may be saved to the same physical partition.
Depends on how many partitions the table has.
How many partitions = max(table size/10gb, (rcu/3000 + wcu/1000))